# How do I host an IPython kernel for remote debugging

Tags: ipython

When a remote process runs into some problem I want to be able to connect to that process with an IPython kernel for remote debugging.  What is the correct way to do this on both the server and client side?

#### Server

How do I start an IPython kernel running in my Python process (which happens to be running a Tornado event loop.)

#### Communicate

What information do I need to send from the server to the client so that it knows how to connect?

#### Client

How do I connect to the remote IPython kernel given the connection information?

Comment: did you find any approach of doing this?